# Telegram CLI/BOT all implicit limits

Tags: api, telegram, limits, python-telegram-bot

I want to send OTP , first to Telegram with usual **SMS fallback**.
Therefore i have to **detect** read callback of OTP message from user only with **telegram cli** API,  unfortunately(Telegram bots doesn't provide read ack. feature).

There is no any concrete info in Telegram.
Is there any **limit** related to telegram bot (and telegram cli) subscribers(contacts) count? Except report spam.
Also what is the limit with native telegram api sendMessage? Which **density** i have to **keep** to **not banned**? Also do i need more numbers or accounts for this?

I searched everywhere and can't find relevant numbers although there are some users with plenty number of accounts.

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE**

Limitations on bot like 30q/sec and etc. is explicit in FAQ. i have to know all **other** limitations, especially on **CLI(max contacts, requests frequency limit)**. For example, i have to know **is this number registered** in telegram - **This is possible only with cli**.Therefore i don't want to abuse platform restrictions, cause of commercial cause. Glad to hear more official ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Bot FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this):

> If you're sending bulk notifications to multiple users, the API will
>   not allow more than 30 messages per second or so. Consider spreading
>   out notifications over large intervals of 8—12 hours for best results.
>
> Also note that your bot will not be able to send more than 20 messages
>   per minute to the same group.

Comment: This limitations is known for everyone. I am asking for other limits like - what is the limit of subscribers on bot or especially contacts in telegram cli. In other words what concrete limits we have on cli for every request. What i have to know before commercial 'soft' use.
I read somewhere that this is like 5k-10k. Please